# Error running ':ConqueTerm bash'

Tags: bash, vim, vim-plugin, conque

I have installed Conque with vundle using the following line:

```
Bundle 'Conque-Shell'
```

However, when I run `:ConqueTerm bash` I get the folowing error:

```
Error detected while processing function conque_term#open..conque_term#dependency_check..conque_term#load_python:
line    2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/snowch/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/autoload/conque_term/conque_globals.py'
line    3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/snowch/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/autoload/conque_term/conque.py'
line   10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/snowch/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/autoload/conque_term/conque_screen.py'
line   11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/snowch/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/autoload/conque_term/conque_subprocess.py'
An error occurred: bash
```

It looks as though conque hasn't fully installed because the files it is looking for don't exist:

```
snowch$ ls /Users/snowch/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/autoload/
conque_term.vim
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, it looks like it is an open defect with conque: https://code.google.com/p/conque/issues/detail?id=80&q=vundle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First issue in the github page is [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell/pull/1). So, you need to use this fork:

```
Bundle 'lrvick/Conque-Shell'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I decided to install without vundle, but still automate the install using:

```
$ vim 'https://conque.googlecode.com/files/conque_2.3.vmb' -c ':so % | q'
```

See [my other question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971275/how-to-automate-installing-conque-term) for more info.

Comment: Kewl, you learn something new every day. I did not know this was an option for vim.