# how to automate installing conque term?

Tags: vim, conque

I've tried installing conque using vundle [but not had any success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970621/error-running-conqueterm-bash) so I'm trying to install manually using the [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage#1.3_Installation) online:

1. download https://conque.googlecode.com/files/conque_2.3.vmb
2. Open the .vba file with Vim and run the following commands:

   `:so %`

   `:q`

How can I automate installing vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have worked, so I'm documenting it in case it is useful for others:

```
$ vim 'https://conque.googlecode.com/files/conque_2.3.vmb' -c ':so % | q'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my simple bash script to install vim (after cloning .dotfiles), Vundle, and install all plugins specified in .vimrc

```
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
vim -c 'PluginInstall' -c 'qa!'
```

It will open vim and show the Vundle plugins as they install with the  native progress indicators and all that, then quit automatically when its finished. Bash scripts below will still be executed once vim is done and exits.